# Have git use proxy only if VPN is active or on corporate network

Tags: git, proxy

I use git on a corporate network that requires a proxy to access github.
I have set the proxy in `.gitconfig` and it works fine from the network.

When I am not in the office, I connect to the corporate network via VPN.
Git works fine like that too.

If i disconnect from the VPN git cannot resolve the proxy (as expected), failing with `fatal: unable to access '...': Could not resolve proxy: ...`.

Is there a way for git to only use the proxy if it needs to?

I don't want to have to keep editing the config depending on if the VPN is active.

In `Rust`, the `cargo` command can pull from github with zero config with or without the VPN active. It would be nice if git on windows could do the same.

Comment: `cargo` doesn't normally use GitHub.  If you're using it such that it does, are you configuring the `http_proxy` environment variable?

Comment: It downloads dependencies listed in `Cargo.toml` from github. You can even specify a github url in there directly. I have not configured anything for it. I assume it just uses the `.pac` config

Comment: Are you using HTTPS in one case and SSH in the other?  There's no reason Cargo should behave differently in this regard; I checked the source.

Comment: https for both git and cargo.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could use a git alias to set and unset the proxy? (I know that you're technically still editing the config, but I can't think of a way you could do this automatically, as profiles rely on the file path.)

For example, to set the proxy with a `setproxy` alias:

```
git config --global alias.setproxy 'config --global http.proxy http://example-proxy'
```

And to unset using a `noproxy` alias:

```
git config --global alias.noproxy 'config --global --unset http.proxy'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following utility marin.jb.free.fr/proxydriver/
which allows you to set proxy when only VPN is in use.

To this I added in the vpn .conf file:

```
git_http_proxy=<proxy url>
git_http_port=911
git_https_proxy=<proxy url>
git_https_port=912
```

and in the .99proxydriver.sh script:

```
rm /etc/gitconfig

if [ "$enabled" == 'true' ]
then
        echo "setting git"         
        git config --system http.proxy "http://${git_http_proxy}:${git_http_port}"
        git config --system https.proxy "http://${git_https_proxy}:${git_https_port}"        
 fi
```